# Why in the visual studio in the solution explorer some folders are not exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

On the hard disk I see all the folders and they are exist:

[image: Folders exist]

Audio,Prefabs,Scripts they are all under the folder FirstPersonCharacter

This three folders also exist in the editor in the Project:

[image: Folders exist]

But in the visual studio in the solution explorer this three folders are not exist.
I tried to refresh I tried to close and open the visual studio again, nothing helped.

[image: Folders not exist]

No folders under FirstPersonCharacter
And if I'm trying to create new folder in the solution explorer under FirstPersonCharacter with the name Scripts I'm getting message it's already exist.

Comment: cannot verify right now, but I think you need to toggle the "show all files and folders" button and then the missing folders will appear dimmed and you right-click them and "include in project".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution Explorer shows the items in your solution; if the folders are not a part of your solution they are not shown by default. You can either add them to your solution (Project > Add Existing Item) or toggle Show All Files in the Explorer to show files not part of your solution.

Note that toggling Show All Files will still not include the files in your solution; if you need to use them you must add them to your solution.